# Number points along polyline while keeping information on preceding point

Tags: point, rivers, numbering

I'm working with river networks and need to create ID for points along it. Trick is that points need to have its own ID and also keep the ID of the preceding point (in  two separate columns of course).

It would look like this:

[image]

Are there any tools/plugins in QGIS that I could use to create such data? Preferably without coding.

Comment: ArcGIS and QGIS would have completely different solutions, therefore this is two different questions. Please [edit] the question to choose one software framework to conform to the "One question per Question" policy.

Comment: What kind of points you need to make, random or by rule?

Comment: I already have points. I only need to assign a new ID depending on the point's location along the polyline (river network)

Comment: If you can use ArcMap then RivEX has a tool that can generate a table which you could then sort and return the required information which you would join back to your input point data. The help page for this tool is [here](http://www.rivex.co.uk/Online-Manual/Findsitesdownstreamofasite.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that was used at the end included QGIS and FME, so it went a bit outside of the scope of the question.

First I created a line shapefile in QGIS and manualy drew individual lines connecting points. It was important to draw single lines (not polylines) and draw them in the desired direction. Meaning to draw from the preceeding point to the receiving one, i.e. on my original picture it would be start drawing in point 1 and end at 2. 2 to 3 and so on.

Then I used FME and SpatialRelator tool to get the order of points.